# scrollByY jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Trying to just assign scrollByY with a pixel amount to an instance of jscrollPane. I'm using it in conjunction with Galleria, and had to add it to the end of the galleria file in order for it to work. code below:

```
        this.bind('loadfinish', function(e) {
        this.$('loader').fadeOut(200);
        $('.galleria-thumbnails-container').jScrollPane({showArrows:true, animateScroll:true});});
```

can't seem to get it to work. I tried using the code from the site:

```
var element = $('.galleria-thumbnails-container').jScrollPane({scrollByY(200)});
var api = element.data('jsp');
```

but that didn't seem to work :( Any help?

Here's a link to the page:
http://orangepxl.com/veronica/galleries.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(function()
{
var pane = $('.galleria-thumbnails-container');
pane.jScrollPane(
    {
        showArrows: true,
        animateScroll: true
    }
);
var api = pane.data('jsp');

$('.jspArrow').bind(
    'click',
    function()
    {
        api.scrollByY(200);
        return false;
    }
);
});
```